# Defining python loggers for shared modules

Tags: python, django, logging

I have, hopefully, a simple question on python/django logging.

I am writing a Django app, which calls some modules that are shared with other processes, jobs, scripts and possibly even some other apps in due course - for example common calculations.

I have configured logging for my Django app in settings.py and then in my main app modules (views.py, etc) I get the logger via:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('exampleApp')
```

Everything works as expected.

However, when my app calls modules in other packages that are shared I obviously do not want to have the same logging.getLogger('exampleApp') call because then other processes that use this module will use an incorrect logger config.

Furthermore using

```
logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

means that when I call this module from my Django app, it doesn't log to the correct file.

So my question is, for shared modules, is there a way for the logger to use the instance in the 'parent caller', in other words a Django app or a standalone server process, or script and so on?  Or is it as simple as having to pass the logger instance into classes defined in the module (as a param in the constructor)?

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider using a modern error logging and aggregation platform like [sentry](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sentry), the comment system is not large enough to describe the benefits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I have got this to work, without passing around logger objects, is to change

```
logger = logging.getLogger('exampleApp')
```

in the top level module to

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
```

so that it actually gets the `root` logger. This root logger format will be followed by other modules.